# Readable list of logical fallacies

Tags: discussion

There seem to be many different lists of logical fallacies available.

Is there one that can be recommended for helping people who don't understand the nature of a logical argument.

My goal here is to help them handle the snipes of "Begging the Question!" or "Strawman!" without them feeling picked upon, and without feeling (as one young man complained after seeing the one on Wikipedia) that the skeptics are just imposing their own made up rules.

Comment: I find pointing out people's cognitive biases is *way* more annoying to them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases

Comment: There's a question on meta to discuss whether this sort of question is on-topic or not: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32/in-what-manner-are-nt-questions-about-logic-or-logical-fallacies-on-topic

Answer (score 10):

This is the best breakdown I've seen:  http://www.fallacyfiles.org/taxonomy.html

Comment: I love the diagram, and hope to reference it again, but having tried to read some of their examples (Masked Man Fallacy, Some Are Not), I found them a little challenging to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who regards arguments being called by their proper names as "the skeptics are just imposing their own made up rules" may be beyond mere logic, let alone lists. You will need to first inculcate a faint regard for logic itself.

Answer (score 1):

The SGU has a top 20:

http://www.theskepticsguide.org/resources/logicalfallacies.aspx